# Localization text error PLAYBACK_CONTROLS_VIEW_CONTROLLER

Tags: video, localization, video-player

I am playing video in webview. I have localization in my project. I am getting `PLAYBACK_CONTROLS_VIEW_CONTROLLER` text.

In which file do I need to set its localized text?

Answer (score 0):

Add `"PLAYBACK_CONTROLS_VIEW_CONTROLLER"` as key and value that you want to show in **Localizable.string** file.